# Not Getting Aggregated values from my reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hashmap

I wrote map reduce program to find the top words based on "key". I used a HashMap to collect the reducer output and did some comparison to get top words and finally I used cleanup() method to print my output.But when I see the result its not showing me the aggregated values in the key.

This is my reducer code.

So,please help me on this I was trying to get this right , since from the past few days.

```
public class top5reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text>
{
    Map<Integer,Text> map=new HashMap<Integer,Text>();
        public void reduce(Iterable<IntWritable> key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException,NullPointerException
    {

        int sum1=0;

for(IntWritable key2:key)
        {
            sum1 +=key2.get();

        }   
map.put(sum1,value);



    } 
protected void cleanup(Context context)
{
    int key=0;
    Text val=null;
Map<Integer,Text> map1=new TreeMap<Integer,Text>(new Comparator<Integer>()
        {
    public int compare(Integer o1,Integer o2)
    {
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
        });
        map1.putAll(map);
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Text>> set=map1.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Text> entr:set)
        {
            key=entr.getKey();
            val=entr.getValue();
        }
        try {
            context.write(new IntWritable(key), val);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem in your reduce function. As you are trying to aggregate for each key, you have to traverse through all values and add them.Try below code and see if it works.

```
 public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterable<IntWritable> value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException,NullPointerException
        {

            int sum1=0;

    for(IntWritable key2:value)
            {
                sum1 +=key2.get();

            }   
    map.put(key,sum1);



        }
```

Comment: In the code value is not iterbale .So,we cannot iterate over the value.Though I checked making value as Iterable but this time it is emittng total count.

Comment: At reducer you get iterable of values, Refer to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html for more information on Reducer.